# If I want to query the same table twice in not in clause, can I use the same table alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example, I have the following relations.

```
Suppliers( sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog( sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
```

I write the following MYSQL query to find the sids of suppliers who supply only red parts.

Example 1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.sid FROM Catalog C 
WHERE C.sid NOT IN(
    SELECT C.sid FROM Catalog C 
    INNER JOIN Parts P ON p.pid = C.pid
    WHERE P.color <> "red"
);
```

Example 2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.sid FROM Catalog C 
WHERE C.sid NOT IN(
    SELECT C2.sid FROM Catalog C2 
    INNER JOIN Parts P ON p.pid = C2.pid
    WHERE P.color <> "red"
);
```

I would like to know if there is any difference bet. the above two query statements. If I want to reuse the same table twice in a nested query, do I have to name my table alias differently? I assume that inner query gets executed first before the outer query so Example 1 should be correct, but I cannot be sure because example 2 is the way the professor taught.

Comment: The name should be scoped to the subquery so you should be able to use it again without problem. I think I would personally just not use an alias on the outer query, in this case, although in general I would use a different alias for clarity. You shouldn't really think of it as getting "executed first "though.

Comment: You can use just joins to solve your problem. No need of a NOT IN

Comment: @shawnt So it is not necessary to name the inner table alias C2 right?  In NOT IN clause, the inner query table alias is independent of outer query table alias?

Comment: Each inner query is COMPLETELY independent. You can reuse the same alias as many as you'd like. You can use the alias "X" in the inner query and then again in the outer one (etc.).

Comment: Yes, but note you can not longer refer to the outer query when you do that. I said "should" because there are many platforms with their own little quirks and I've never tried that on MySQL that I recall.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I know how to use join to find suppliers who supply red parts. but the problem asks me to find suppliers who supply only red part, I cannot find a way to solve this problem without using nested query

Comment: In this situation you are correct. You have to use this kind of an operator. (In / Exists / All etc.)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no difference between your two queries. They are exactly the same. The only difference is that you are using different alias for the table `Catalog`on then. The parser will resolve the alias from most inside to outside so in your query example 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.sid FROM Catalog C 
 WHERE C.sid NOT IN(
              SELECT C.sid FROM Catalog C
                        INNER JOIN Parts P ON p.pid = C.pid
                WHERE P.color <> "red"
             );
```

The `Catalog` from subquery with alias `C` will no be the same as the outside query. Because the parser will resolve it as if it was another table.

No matter the alias you use the parser will resolve from inside (subqueries) to outsise. Hope you have understanded.

Although depending the operators you use you can use the outer alias inside a subquery. Like the query below.

To solve your problem you can use an NOT EXISTS clause joining with the outer table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.sid 
  FROM Catalog C 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
          FROM Catalog Cin 
                 INNER JOIN Parts P ON p.pid = Cin.pid
         WHERE P.color <> 'red'
           AND Cin.sid=C.sid );
```

Comment: It works perfect after I change line 3 to "WHERE NOT EXISTS" for it to work with mysql.  Thank you for clarification.  :)

Comment: ooooh my mistake. you are totally right. Edited it.

Comment: @GuanSummyHuang Consider in accepting the answer if, only if, it trully helped you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your queries will both work. Should you want to do it without a subquery try this:

```
select c.sid
from Catalog c inner join Parts p on p.pid = c.sid
group by c.sid
having min(p.color) = 'red' and max(p.color) = 'red'
```

or

```
having count(case when p.color = 'red' then 1 else null end) = count(*)
```

And here's another approach in case you're interested. It lets you easily grab all the supplier info at once:

```
select *
from Suppliers s
where 'red' = all (
    select p.color
    from Catalog c inner join Parts p on p.pid = c.pid
    where c.sid = s.sid
)
```

Comment: the line "p.sid" gives me the error "Unknown column 'p.sid' in 'where clause". Table Parts don't have the attibute sid. I think there should be another join

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that `sid` was in your parts table.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to use not in for this scenario.your are close to your answer. Please try the following query;

```
select c.sid from Catalog as c
inner join Parts as p on c.pid=p.pid
WHERE P.color <> "red"
group by c.sid
```